# Eclipse not showing import option in quick fix

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Don't know but now my Eclipse is not showing import option automatically but I can add them manually

I was trying to do imports using quick fix in Eclipse

Comment: Have you tried it through Content Assist, or Organizing Imports?